# Ensuring Excel calcs are refreshed whilst running VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running a simple macro, with `Application.Calculation` set to `xlCalculationManual`.  In a loop (with thousands of iterations), the macro:

- Writes inputs for the iteration to cells in a worksheet
- Runs the `Worksheet.Calculate` method
- Grabs values returned by formulas on the worksheet
- Writes these values to a different worksheet

I'd always assumed `Worksheet.Calculate` guarantees the values returned by my formulas would be up-to-date.

But some recent debugging suggested that may be not.

I found these whilst researching this:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c25e60f3-fbd6-4ced-9b56-9265ecc95577/vba-applicationcalculate-unreliable-?forum=exceldev
http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/07/01/interrupting-calculations/
But they're a few years old, and I wondered if there's any more recent advice.

Do folks recommend setting `Application.CalculationInterruptKey` to `xlNoKey` (or to `xlEscKey`), prior to running the code, and then returning it to its original value upon completion?

Or putting `Worksheet.Calculate` in a while loop that checks for `Application.CalculationState = xlDone`?

Or some other approach?

Are there any nuances or adverse side effects I should be taking into account (I recently utilized `DoEvents` to help solve a problem, but it ended up causing other problems, so would like to avoid something similar).

Thanks all,

Jim

Comment: The "writes inputs to cells in a worksheet" part is presumably operating on a cell-by-cell basis? Have you considered dumping inputs into a 2D variant array and writing to the sheet *once* per iteration instead? That way you could leave calculation automatic, and avoid the problem entirely.

Comment: I have no additional knowledge of whether this has changed, but I have had enough problems with unexpected calculation behaviors within the past decade to feel confidant that you should not just rely on it working any better today than when that was written.  I’d definitely recommend using the loop with calculationState, but put some low limit on it, because I’ve seen many a huge excel workbook go into permanent recalc, even without circular references.